# IsDate() with datetype variable in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a following code

```
declare @dt date
set @dt = '7/5/2010 12:00:00 AM '
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, CASE ISDATE(@dt) WHEN 1 THEN @dt ELSE NULL END)
```

It throws an error

> Argument data type date is invalid for argument 1 of isdate function.

It's because the variable is `date` type

Now I tried this way

```
declare @dt date
set @dt = '7/5/2010'
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, CASE ISDATE( convert(varchar, @dt ,105)   ) WHEN 1 THEN @dt ELSE NULL END)
```

and it worked.

But when I have put wrong date like

```
declare @dt date
set @dt = '7/5/201ss0'
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, CASE ISDATE( convert(varchar, @dt ,105)   ) WHEN 1 THEN @dt ELSE NULL END)
```

Error :

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

My scenario is I have a huge excel file that I am reading through **c# oled** and doing table type for Bulk Upload, so I don't want to check in my C# code

How can I overcome with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend moving the test outside the CONVERT function, like this:

```
declare @dt varchar(20)
set @dt = '7/5/2010'
SELECT CASE ISDATE(@dt) WHEN 1 THEN CONVERT(DATE, @dt) ELSE NULL END
```

Comment: it throows erro when @dt is datetype

Comment: data type of @dt is date

Comment: data type of @dt should be varchar. The select statement will return a data type of DATE

Comment: I assume you are trying to use the select statement to make sure it returns DATE only, and never fails regardless of what have been passed as @dt parameter. The use cases for this trick are: `INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT...`, or a case where an application expects a DATE from the select statement, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to create an invalid date, the error occurs during assignment. Note that you get the same error here, without ever running your `CASE` / `ISDATE` expression:

```
declare @dt date
set @dt = '7/5/201ss0'
```

Result:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

So, a few things:

1. Why would you ever try to assign an invalid string to a date?
2. Why would you ever use an ambiguous date format like 7/5/2012 as a date - is that July 5th or May 7th? Who knows? Does SQL Server know? Depends on language, dateformat, regional settings, etc.
3. If your parameter really is a `DATE` parameter, then there is no reason to test `ISDATE()`. Other than `NULL`, you can't assign an invalid date to a `DATE` data type.

Comment: its reading from excel file, so it there could be any thing in field

Comment: Then why does your question say DECLARE @dt DATE? If you are pulling data in from an Excel file, then explain your problem in full. My answer explains why you get the error you get with the code you put in your question. If you can't assign an invalid value to the variable, there is no point in subsequently checking the variable - it's too late if the assignment didn't work in the first place.

Comment: I have mention everything in question dear